# Under what circumstances will the completed pod not be recycled

Tags: kubernetes, nextflow

Recently, there have been a lot of completed pods on the k8s cluster, which I suspect is related to insufficient cluster resources

The nextflow task I created contains several processes, usually they will be executed sequentially, and a new pod will be created after the previous pod is completed. But recently, a large number of tasks have been submitted on the cluster. During the observation process, many completed pods appeared, and the tasks got stuck. I'm wondering if this has something to do with cluster resources or nextflow, and what else could happen if this pod keeps failing to recycle?

Answer (score 1):

Need more details however if your **POD** are being completed which means code is being executed properly.

In any case, if your **POD** throwing **Error** or **Failed** it should **crash** and not change status to **Completed**.

If there is a resource issue in K8s POD won't schedule at all and will stuck in a **pending** state.

Another case could be POD start **crashing** or get **OOM kill** event so in this case you have to keep checking status of POD.